# Diagnosing very slow read from unix socket using golang (1 min vs 1 sec in netcat)

Tags: go, unix-socket

**Background**
Im writing a few packages to communicate with the OpenVas vulnerability scanner - the scanner uses a few different propitiatory protocols to communicate - are all comprised of either xml or text strings sent over a unix socket or tcp connection (im using unix socket).

The issue I'm having is with the OTP protocol (OpenVas internal protocol which is not well documented)

I can run the following command using netcat and I will get a response back in under a second:

> echo -en '< OTP/2.0 >\nCLIENT <|> NVT_INFO\n' | ncat -U
>   /var/run/openvassd.sock

This results in a fairly large response which looks like this in terminal:

```
< OTP/2.0 >
SERVER <|> NVT_INFO <|> 201802131248 <|> SERVER
SERVER <|> PREFERENCES <|>
cache_folder <|> /var/cache/openvas
include_folders <|> /var/lib/openvas/plugins
max_hosts <|> 30
//lots more here
```

So for example, I previously had some code like this for reading the response back:

```
func (c Client) read() ([]byte, error) {

    // set up buffer to read in chunks
    bufSize := 8096
    resp := []byte{}
    buf := make([]byte, bufSize)

    for {
        n, err := c.conn.Read(buf)
        resp = append(resp, buf[:n]...)
        if err != nil {
            if err != io.EOF {
                return resp, fmt.Errorf("read error: %s", err)
            }
            break
        }
        fmt.Println("got", n, "bytes.")

    }
    fmt.Println("total response size:", len(resp))

    return resp, nil
}
```

I get the full result but it comes in small pieces (i guess line by line) so the output I see is something like this (over the course of a minute or so before showing full response):

```
got 53 bytes.
got 62 bytes.
got 55 bytes.
got 62 bytes.
got 64 bytes.
got 59 bytes.
got 58 bytes.
got 54 bytes.
got 54 bytes.
got 54 bytes.
got 64 bytes.
got 59 bytes.
... (more)
```

SO I decided to try ioutil.ReadAll:

```
func (c Client) read() ([]byte, error) {
    fmt.Println("read start")
    d, err := ioutil.ReadAll(c.conn)
    fmt.Println("read done")
    return d, err
}
```

This does again return the full response, but the time between "read start" and "read done" is around a minute compared to the < 1sec the command is expected to take.

Any thoughts on why the read via golang is so slow compared to netcat - how can I diagnose/fix the issue?**

Comment: `ReadAll` waits for `io.EOF`

Comment: @JimB apologies you are quite correct, I assumed it was hitting EOF, in fact a little more poking revealed that is not the case - I have updated my question - any thoughts on why the response is taking so long via go?

Comment: I don't understand the question, but maybe the confusion is because you're not correctly reading from the socket in the first place. A `Read` call is never guaranteed to return the buffer size of bytes, it returns what's available. Read the [`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) documentation again. You must check the number of bytes read first, before checking for an error. Reading fewer bytes than your buffer size is not indicative of anything.

Comment: I would add that a few of the links at the bottom of [this document](http://www.openvas.org/compendium/openvas-compendium.html) broadly describe that protocol, and googling reveals that OpenVAS is open source, so one can just read its source code to get an idea about how a message boundary should be detected when working with this protocol. (Though I think JimB is correct

Comment: as per updated question, I have removed the bit that returns if the response is less than the buffer size, I now get the full response back in dribs and drabs. The outstanding issue is why it is taking so long to return the full response (either via read or ReadAll) when netcat pulls it back in under a second. @Kostix, there are no docs (up to date) so looking through the source code is the only way I've got anywhere with this but I dont think the issue im seeing is to do with openvas or the protocol as netcat is coping just fine with no knowledge.

Comment: @WebweaverD: you have not removed it: `if n < bufSize {`. That there is an error itself. Break the loop after you handle the bytes read, when you handle the error.

Comment: @JimB - just had some text explaining the change, have updated source and question now to clarify

Comment: Btw I thing now with this code you will never fulfill `if n == 0` because this case - in case of EOF or other err - has already been covered earlier inside your loop.

Comment: thanks, I had suspected - I will remove

Comment: @WebweaverD: I'm not sure how to make this more clear -- handle the bytes read _first_, check the error after. From the [`io.Reader` documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader): `Callers should always process the n > 0 bytes returned before considering the error err.`

Comment: @JimB thanks for the suggestion (missed in previous comment) - that doesn't seem to make any difference to the response time, I have changed anyway as I guess there is a chance of losing the part of the message when reading the error first

Comment: I had also thought that perhaps it was constant appends or printing to stdout slowing it down, but I have tried removing the Printlns and using a bytes.Buffer and this only make a marginal difference - still very slow

Comment: @WebweaverD: as for response time, you say in the post they both take about a minute -- so what exactly is the question now?

Comment: both my attempts in go take a minute, via netcat it takes a second - that is the question why the ~59 second discrepancy between go and netcat - I would expect similar performance

Comment: @WebweaverD: OK, I see what you're asking now. First guess is that the `openvassd` service is waiting for input -- try calling `CloseWrite` after you send your command. Otherwise I would trace the command and see exactly what it's doing.

Comment: Sounds reasonable but I cant see a way of doing that -  I write to the connection using c.conn.Write(data), there is no c.conn.CloseWrite() method on the net.Conn object, only .Close() which I presume will close for reading also.

Comment: @WebweaverD, `c.conn.(*net.UnixConn).CloseWrite()` should have you covered. The reason is that you appear to use the generic connection function, `net.Dial`, which returns an interface value, `net.Conn` (since it's, well, generic).  You might use `net.DialUnix` to get a value of the concrete type, `net.UnixConn` back. Still, when you pass "unix" as the 1st argument to `net.Dial`, you'll get an instance of `net.UnixConn` back, so it's safe to type-assert it.

Comment: @JimB thank you - that seems to be the issue, I did a quick test and the response came back immediately - if you want to present as an answer I will gladly accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the service is waiting for more input, and eventually times out after a minute. In your CLI example, once the `echo` command completes that side of the pipe is shutdown for writes, in which case the service is notified by a 0-length recv.

In order to do the same in Go, you need to call [`CloseWrite`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#UnixConn.CloseWrite) on the `net.UnixConn` after you have completed sending the command.

```
c.conn.(*net.UnixConn).CloseWrite()
```

Comment: JFTR, `CloseWrite()` calls [`shutdown(fd, SHUT_WR)`](https://manpages.debian.org/2/shutdown) on POSIX systems; hope this might explain more to the OP about this behaviour.